# Wrong number of parameters

Tags: php, sql, phalcon, prepared-statements

Estoy usando prepares statements para mejorar una consulta que estoy realizando, pero me genera el error:

> Wrong number of parameters

El código es el siguiente:

```
$start = new DateTime('first monday of January 2016');
$end   = new DateTime('last day of December 2016');

$sql = "SELECT ".$generalLand."
                         product AS product,
                         Week AS label,
                         ROUND(SUM(harvest)/SUM(production),2) AS value
                  FROM (
                          (
                              SELECT ".$fieldLand."
                                     pr_products.product,
                                     CONCAT(YEAR(:dates),'-', LPAD(WEEK(:dates1),2,'0')) AS Week,
                                     SUM(IF(sw_sowing.type = 'SW', sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS PlantSowing,
                                     SUM(IF(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates2)),:dates3), sw_sowing.date)/7) >= pr_products.week_production AND sw_sowing.type = 'SW',sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS production,
                                     0 AS Harvest
                              FROM (
                                      SELECT max(sw_sowing.id) AS id
                                      FROM sw_sowing
                                      WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
                                      AND sw_sowing.date <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates4)),:dates5)
                                      GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
                                   ) AS sw
                              INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
                              INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product
                              INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON sw_sowing.id_variety = pr_varieties.id
                              ".$innerSowing."
                              WHERE pr_varieties.code != 1
                              AND sw_sowing.id_product = 1
                              AND sw_sowing.status = 100
                              AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = :id_tenant
                              ".$consultSowing."
                              GROUP BY pr_products.product
                              HAVING plantSowing > 0
                              ORDER BY pr_products.product
                          )
                          UNION ALL
                          (
                              SELECT  ".$fieldLand."
                                      pr_products.product,
                                      CONCAT(YEAR(:dates6),'-', LPAD(WEEK(:dates7),2,'0')) AS Week,
                                      0 AS plantSowing,
                                      0 AS Production,
                                      SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS Harvest
                              FROM pf_harvest
                              INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
                              INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = pf_harvest.id_variety
                              INNER JOIN pf_performance ON pf_performance.id = pf_harvest.id_performance
                              ".$innerHarvest."
                              WHERE pf_harvest.date BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(0-WEEKDAY(:dates8)),:dates9)
                              AND TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates10)),:dates11)
                              AND pr_varieties.code != 1
                              AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
                              AND pf_performance.status = 100
                              ".$consultHarvest."
                              AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = :id_tenant1
                              GROUP BY pr_products.product
                              ORDER BY pr_products.product
                              )
                          ) AS sc
                  GROUP BY product, label
                  ORDER BY label";

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $id_tenant = $this->getIdTenant();
        foreach($datePeriod AS $dates){

          $values = [
            ':dates'      => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates1'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates2'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates3'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates4'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates5'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates6'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates7'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates8'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates9'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates10'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates11'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':id_tenant'  => $id_tenant,
            ':id_tenant1' => $id_tenant

          ];

          $result = $this->db->executePrepared($statement , $values);

        }
```

He estado mirando pero no he podido encontrar el error o el por qué del error, si alguien puede darme una sugerencia se lo agradecería.

Comment: en $consultSowing y $consultHarvest no tienes algun parametro `:parametro` ?

Comment: No, ninguno son sólo campos de una tabla cuando se seleccione una opción

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que investigue,

En Phalcon, la funcion executedPrepared recibe 3 parametros.

```
public PDOStatement executePrepared (
            PDOStatement $statement, 
            array $placeholders, 
            array $dataTypes)
```

Espero esta sea la solución, me comentas.

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/api/Phalcon_Db_Adapter_Pdo.html

Comment: Es que use los 3 parámetros y tampoco me funcionó, pero voy a revisar si es que hay lago mal! gracias !

Comment: La verdad es lo que pude ver en tu código, ya que por el error el único que calzaba con el error era esa función. Si descubre el problema, comparte.

Comment: Si @jolsalazar si funcionó era eso ! Muchas gracias! saludos!

Comment: genial!! =) saludos,